# C++ error "Variable or field declared void"

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this error: "Variable or field declared void".

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

//Map per gestire il dizionario
std::map <std::string, Word> Dictionary;

int main()
{
    create_word();
    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
#include <iostream> //Libreria I/O
#include <string> //Libreria per le String
#include <map> //Libreria per le Map
#include "class_word.h" //Libreria con classe Word
#include "function_dictionary.cpp" //Funzioni sul dizionario
#include "function_word.cpp" //Funzioni sulla classe Word
```

class_word.h

```
//Classe Word, rappresenta la parola del dizionario
class Word {
//Attributi privati della classe Word
private:
    std::string value; //Valore
    std::string desc; //Descrizione

//Metodi pubblici della classe Word
public:
    Word() {} //Costruttore
    Word(std::string val, std::string des) {value=val; desc=des;} //Costruttore con argomenti
    ~Word(){} //Distruttore
    std::string get_Value() {return value;} //Metodo per prendere la parola
    std::string get_Desc() {return desc;} //Metodo per prendere la descrizione
};
```

function_word.cpp

```
//Funzione per la creazione di una word
void create_word ()
{
    //Dichiarazione variabili
    std::string word, description;

    std::cout << "Parola: "; std::cin >> word;
    std::cout << "Descrizione: "; std::cin >> description;

    //Creazione Word
    Word temp(word, description);

    //Inserimento nel dizionario
    insert_dictionary(temp);
}
```

function_dictionary.cpp

```
//Funzione per inserire la parola nel dizionario
void insert_dictionary (Word temp)
{
    Dictionary.insert(make_pair(temp.get_Value(), temp));
}
```

At last file i have the error...How can i resolve?
I think that was a bad include of file, but i can't resolve it...
Help me pls...i am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is declared in `main.cpp` but nowhere else; you're then trying to use it in `function_dictionary.cpp`. It is undeclared there. You will need to put the declaration of `Dictionary` in one of the header files, using `extern`, which is included by both `.cpp` files.

This question fully explains how to share `Dictionary` between both source files, and shows how to use the `extern` keyword: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)

Also, it is generally bad practice to `#include` a `.cpp` file. This is almost certain to cause problems. The more common pattern is to *declare* everything in headers, then *define* things in `.cpp` files.

Comment: How can i resolve this problem to not use much include?

Comment: Includes are fine, just don't include `.cpp` files. See the link in my answer for an explanation of how to share variables in two source files using an `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of inclusion:

firstly you include `function_dictionary.cpp` (via `header.h`) which uses the global symbol `Dictionary` which is strictly defined after that in the `main.cpp`

You break up too much these include things, it's not required.

Comment: Yes, i think that it's this...How i can resolve that problem? What are the include not required?

Comment: since this is a tiny project put all methods in main.cpp after where you define `Dictionary` (emphasize is on the tiny project, usually for bigger projects you have a much clearer file organization) ... or just include "header.h" after the definition but then include <map>  and "class_word.h".... before the Dictionary definition ... ;)